# Golang алгоритм XTEA ECB библиотека "golang.org/x/crypto/xtea"

Tags: golang, криптография

Имею зашифрованные данные, как расшифровать их используя библиотеку  "golang.org/x/crypto/xtea"?

Исходный массив:

```
60614e680e705d0fefcf7ac8102c4452
ecb0c85768f2f2dc52415c43a36712f0
31c9037dafd31f01ecb0c85768f2f2dc
7b00be7e5a15fee1e78c63c58c2c6861
fef9a1c4130a354c846448512e6a97ce
4a9005690d1e3808f065c957538e1bac
87e7228322ab39a6900146786840dc0b
c536ad6afb6e4e3267fb045dd9c7e670
f1c2d2ac1fcc71ad06b7b194de4031f4
046744610aafa7b92fd3f392c3a5eeb1
474ffa60c0587e68ecb0c85768f2f2dc
2a88827461b41c99b2539b6bfdcd4325
be3ced59be7b594addb3366e076f6e47
0cc41df1eb3a8d93c99eb7bdad5a474c
33659653762910d0ecb0c85768f2f2dc
ecb0c85768f2f2dc82e715e7952a79c4
660074ccc50741cab5eabb873ae706b4
c8b008128df0af80fece91741fc5f641
1145aab35ac9f6e0f8a937baed012d00
c3be705a5e8c3440ddc1cd4e0051cccc
```

Пробую расшифровать подобным образом, но на выходе получаются неправильные данные:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/xtea"
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    // зашифрованные данные добавил 0x, что бы golang не ругался
    test :=[]byte{
            0x60, 0x61, 0x4e, 0x68, 0x0e, 0x70, 0x5d, 0x0f, 0xef, 0xcf, 0x7a, 0xc8, 0x10, 0x2c, 0x44, 0x52,
            0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc, 0x52, 0x41, 0x5c, 0x43, 0xa3, 0x67, 0x12, 0xf0,
            0x31, 0xc9, 0x03, 0x7d, 0xaf, 0xd3, 0x1f, 0x01, 0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc,
            0x7b, 0x00, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0x5a, 0x15, 0xfe, 0xe1, 0xe7, 0x8c, 0x63, 0xc5, 0x8c, 0x2c, 0x68, 0x61,
            0xfe, 0xf9, 0xa1, 0xc4, 0x13, 0x0a, 0x35, 0x4c, 0x84, 0x64, 0x48, 0x51, 0x2e, 0x6a, 0x97, 0xce,
            0x4a, 0x90, 0x05, 0x69, 0x0d, 0x1e, 0x38, 0x08, 0xf0, 0x65, 0xc9, 0x57, 0x53, 0x8e, 0x1b, 0xac,
            0x87, 0xe7, 0x22, 0x83, 0x22, 0xab, 0x39, 0xa6, 0x90, 0x01, 0x46, 0x78, 0x68, 0x40, 0xdc, 0x0b,
            0xc5, 0x36, 0xad, 0x6a, 0xfb, 0x6e, 0x4e, 0x32, 0x67, 0xfb, 0x04, 0x5d, 0xd9, 0xc7, 0xe6, 0x70,
            0xf1, 0xc2, 0xd2, 0xac, 0x1f, 0xcc, 0x71, 0xad, 0x06, 0xb7, 0xb1, 0x94, 0xde, 0x40, 0x31, 0xf4,
            0x04, 0x67, 0x44, 0x61, 0x0a, 0xaf, 0xa7, 0xb9, 0x2f, 0xd3, 0xf3, 0x92, 0xc3, 0xa5, 0xee, 0xb1,
            0x47, 0x4f, 0xfa, 0x60, 0xc0, 0x58, 0x7e, 0x68, 0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc,
            0x2a, 0x88, 0x82, 0x74, 0x61, 0xb4, 0x1c, 0x99, 0xb2, 0x53, 0x9b, 0x6b, 0xfd, 0xcd, 0x43, 0x25,
            0xbe, 0x3c, 0xed, 0x59, 0xbe, 0x7b, 0x59, 0x4a, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0x36, 0x6e, 0x07, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x47,
            0x0c, 0xc4, 0x1d, 0xf1, 0xeb, 0x3a, 0x8d, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9e, 0xb7, 0xbd, 0xad, 0x5a, 0x47, 0x4c,
            0x33, 0x65, 0x96, 0x53, 0x76, 0x29, 0x10, 0xd0, 0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc,
            0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc, 0x82, 0xe7, 0x15, 0xe7, 0x95, 0x2a, 0x79, 0xc4,
            0x66, 0x00, 0x74, 0xcc, 0xc5, 0x07, 0x41, 0xca, 0xb5, 0xea, 0xbb, 0x87, 0x3a, 0xe7, 0x06, 0xb4,
            0xc8, 0xb0, 0x08, 0x12, 0x8d, 0xf0, 0xaf, 0x80, 0xfe, 0xce, 0x91, 0x74, 0x1f, 0xc5, 0xf6, 0x41,
            0x11, 0x45, 0xaa, 0xb3, 0x5a, 0xc9, 0xf6, 0xe0, 0xf8, 0xa9, 0x37, 0xba, 0xed, 0x01, 0x2d, 0x00,
            0xc3, 0xbe, 0x70, 0x5a, 0x5e, 0x8c, 0x34, 0x40, 0xdd, 0xc1, 0xcd, 0x4e, 0x00, 0x51, 0xcc, 0xcc,
            }
    // ключ шифрования
    key := []byte("yuyuyuyuopopopop")
    c, _ := xtea.NewCipher(key)
    myout := make([]byte, len(test))
    // попытка расшифровать
    c.Decrypt(myout, test)

    fmt.Println(myout)
}
```

Данные, которые должны были получиться:

```
09300004100e00000104f47795590210
0000000000000000616161615d5d5d5d
09150000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000d1052545530322e30
312e3030303200000012040000000013
040000000014046161616115045d5d5d
5d1604010e00001704010e0000180401
0e00001904010e00001a04010e00001b
04010e00001c04010e00001d04010e00
001e01001f0100200100210100240100
25113235303032000000000000000000
0000002604ef1400002704930d00002d
01022e02e0012f05ffffffff00300103
3101003301003404050100003d20342e
3132382e323400000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000004401
184f04960d0000500400000000570460
ea0000580422060000590460ea00005a
04e01500005b01005c01025d01005e01
005f010360010361010262010400011b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть кому-то пригодится. Библиотека “golang.org/x/crypto/xtea”, не реализует алгоритм XTEA с моделью ECB из-за его не безопасности, потому написал свой вариант:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    original := []byte{
            0x60, 0x61, 0x4e, 0x68, 0x0e, 0x70, 0x5d, 0x0f, 0xef, 0xcf, 0x7a, 0xc8, 0x10, 0x2c, 0x44, 0x52,
            0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc, 0x52, 0x41, 0x5c, 0x43, 0xa3, 0x67, 0x12, 0xf0,
            0x31, 0xc9, 0x03, 0x7d, 0xaf, 0xd3, 0x1f, 0x01, 0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc,
            0x7b, 0x00, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0x5a, 0x15, 0xfe, 0xe1, 0xe7, 0x8c, 0x63, 0xc5, 0x8c, 0x2c, 0x68, 0x61,
            0xfe, 0xf9, 0xa1, 0xc4, 0x13, 0x0a, 0x35, 0x4c, 0x84, 0x64, 0x48, 0x51, 0x2e, 0x6a, 0x97, 0xce,
            0x4a, 0x90, 0x05, 0x69, 0x0d, 0x1e, 0x38, 0x08, 0xf0, 0x65, 0xc9, 0x57, 0x53, 0x8e, 0x1b, 0xac,
            0x87, 0xe7, 0x22, 0x83, 0x22, 0xab, 0x39, 0xa6, 0x90, 0x01, 0x46, 0x78, 0x68, 0x40, 0xdc, 0x0b,
            0xc5, 0x36, 0xad, 0x6a, 0xfb, 0x6e, 0x4e, 0x32, 0x67, 0xfb, 0x04, 0x5d, 0xd9, 0xc7, 0xe6, 0x70,
            0xf1, 0xc2, 0xd2, 0xac, 0x1f, 0xcc, 0x71, 0xad, 0x06, 0xb7, 0xb1, 0x94, 0xde, 0x40, 0x31, 0xf4,
            0x04, 0x67, 0x44, 0x61, 0x0a, 0xaf, 0xa7, 0xb9, 0x2f, 0xd3, 0xf3, 0x92, 0xc3, 0xa5, 0xee, 0xb1,
            0x47, 0x4f, 0xfa, 0x60, 0xc0, 0x58, 0x7e, 0x68, 0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc,
            0x2a, 0x88, 0x82, 0x74, 0x61, 0xb4, 0x1c, 0x99, 0xb2, 0x53, 0x9b, 0x6b, 0xfd, 0xcd, 0x43, 0x25,
            0xbe, 0x3c, 0xed, 0x59, 0xbe, 0x7b, 0x59, 0x4a, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0x36, 0x6e, 0x07, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x47,
            0x0c, 0xc4, 0x1d, 0xf1, 0xeb, 0x3a, 0x8d, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9e, 0xb7, 0xbd, 0xad, 0x5a, 0x47, 0x4c,
            0x33, 0x65, 0x96, 0x53, 0x76, 0x29, 0x10, 0xd0, 0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc,
            0xec, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0x57, 0x68, 0xf2, 0xf2, 0xdc, 0x82, 0xe7, 0x15, 0xe7, 0x95, 0x2a, 0x79, 0xc4,
            0x66, 0x00, 0x74, 0xcc, 0xc5, 0x07, 0x41, 0xca, 0xb5, 0xea, 0xbb, 0x87, 0x3a, 0xe7, 0x06, 0xb4,
            0xc8, 0xb0, 0x08, 0x12, 0x8d, 0xf0, 0xaf, 0x80, 0xfe, 0xce, 0x91, 0x74, 0x1f, 0xc5, 0xf6, 0x41,
            0x11, 0x45, 0xaa, 0xb3, 0x5a, 0xc9, 0xf6, 0xe0, 0xf8, 0xa9, 0x37, 0xba, 0xed, 0x01, 0x2d, 0x00,
            0xc3, 0xbe, 0x70, 0x5a, 0x5e, 0x8c, 0x34, 0x40, 0xdd, 0xc1, 0xcd, 0x4e, 0x00, 0x51, 0xcc, 0xcc}

    testKey := []byte("yuyuyuyuopopopop")
    block := make([]byte, 8)
    for i := 0; i< len(original)/8; i++ {
        block = decrypt(testKey , original[(i*8):((i+1)*8)], 32)
        fmt.Println(hex.Dump(block))
    }
}

func decrypt(key []byte, block []byte, rounds uint32) ([]byte){
    var k [4]uint32
    var i uint32
    end := make([]byte, 8)
    v0 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(block[:4])
    v1 := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(block[4:])

    k[0] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(key[:4])
    k[1] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(key[4:8])
    k[2] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(key[8:12])
    k[3] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(key[12:])

    delta := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32([]byte{0xb9, 0x79, 0x37, 0x9e})
    mask := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32([]byte{0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff})

    sum := (delta * rounds) & mask

    for i=0; i<rounds; i++ {
        v1 = (v1 - (((v0<<4 ^ v0>>5) + v0) ^ (sum + k[sum>>11 & 3]))) & mask
            sum = (sum - delta) & mask
            v0 = (v0 - (((v1<<4 ^ v1>>5) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]))) & mask
    }

    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(end[:4], v0)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(end[4:], v1)

    return end
}
```